# Generating Google Map Markers with db data via JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, google-api

I am trying to generate markers on the map using data stored in my db.  Currently the map is displayed, no errors in the console.  I assume either I am not accessing the data correctly or the JSON is not formatted correctly.

Currently not using any gems for maps,
Ruby 2.3.3,
Rails  5.1.6,
SQLite db

When I go to riders/json it displays an array with all my rider data.

Have have been trying for a few hours, and searching, trying different solutions. My current set up is the one that does not show errors and in the terminal or when inspecting.  I do see the "GET" request and "Rider Load SELECT "riders".* FROM "riders" with the 200 response in the terminal.

Any help would be appreciated, or explanation on what I am leaving out would be great.

Below is the _map.html.erb file where I am generating the map, I am calling it using <%= render ("layouts/map") %>  on the static page.

```
     <script>
  function initMap() {

        var myLatLng = {lat: 40.014, lng: -105.270};

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 12,
        center: myLatLng
        });




        $.getJSON("/riders.json", function ( data )  {
            $.each(data, function(key, data) {

            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng );

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng,
                map: map
                });
            });
        });



    }

  </script>

  <script async defer
     src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? 
     key=AIzaSyAs2tWVlXznbp6ySamqYXot3sd7wNNLuXI&callback=initMap">
  </script>
```

views/riders/index.json.jbuilder file:

```
    json.array! @riders do |rider|
    json.lat rider.latitude
    json.lng rider.longitude
    end
```

controllers/riders_controller:

```
    class RidersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_rider, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    respond_to? :json  #respond_to w/o ? threw an error

    def index
      @riders = Rider.all
      render json: @riders
    end

    def show
      @rider = Rider.where(id: params[:id])
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json { render json: @rider }
      end
    end
```

This is my first time pulling data to use in an API, any links to further reading would be welcomed as well.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very minor adjustment solved it....

I was relying on my riders.json file to assign the data but it was not.

I edited:

var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng( data.lat , data.lng );

to

var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng( data.latitude , data.longitude );

Wow the time I spent overlooking that basic thing is shocking... but I found using console.log(JSON.stringify(data.longitude));  (and with latitude) was generating the correct data so it came down to my problem that I was not assigning correctly.  I am shocked I didn't figure that out yesterday.   Thank you for whoever took the time to read this.